How should I email a tutor about missing a group formation class?
I was stuck in traffic despite leaving early and couldn't make it to class on time. We were supposed to form groups in this class for a research project. I'm not sure how to email the tutor about this. Should I ask them to assign me to a group through email or is it better to discuss this in a consultation?

Basic person-to-person communication.

You can start your email with a respectful greeting, such as “Dear Professor [Name].” Then briefly explain your situation, mentioning the traffic and your absence from class. Ask if it would be possible to be assigned to a group or if you should discuss this in a consultation. End by thanking them for their understanding. Here is an example:
Dear Professor [Name],
I hope you are well. I am writing to inform you that unfortunately I was unable to attend the group formation class due to traffic problems. I would like to know if it would be possible to be assigned to a group for the research project or if I should discuss this in a consultation. I thank you for your understanding.
Sincerely,
[Your Name]
[Your Course]
[Your Contact]
This is how you address the situation clearly and respectfully.
